# bubble chat for text inside the textarea using javafx

Tags: javafx

want some help to get the bubble chat for the text inside the textarea using javafx, so i have tried to add other methods like left speech bubble and right speech bubble, but thats not working out. so i want the text inside a bubble.

```
private void initComponents(VBox root) {
    incoming = new TextArea();
    double height = 500;
    double width = 300;  
    incoming.setPrefHeight(height); 
    incoming.setPrefWidth(width);
    incoming.setFont(Font.font ("Verdana", 15));
    incoming.setEditable(false);
    incoming.setFocusTraversable(false);
    incoming.setBorder((new Border(
            new BorderStroke(Color.AQUA, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT))));
    incoming.setStyle(
            "-fx-focus-color: -fx-control-inner-background ; -fx-faint-focus-color: -fx-control-inner-background ;  -fx-background-image: url(file:Airbus.jpg)");
    root.getChildren().add(incoming);

    outgoing = new TextField();
    outgoing.setFont(Font.font ("Verdana", 15));

    root.getChildren().add(outgoing);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    send = new Button("SEND");
    send.setOnAction(e -> {
        String text = outgoing.getText();

        if (text.length() > 0) {
            incoming.appendText(userName + ": " + text + "\n");
            outgoing.selectAll();
            writer.println(outgoing.getText());
            writer.flush();
        }
        outgoing.requestFocus();
        outgoing.clear();
    });

    outgoing.setOnKeyPressed(ke -> {
        if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            send.fire();
        }
    });
    send.setPrefSize(WIDTH, 30);
    root.getChildren().add(send);

    userName = WindowUtils.buildTextDialog("What is your name?", "Please enter your name :", "Name");
    //greet user:
    incoming.appendText("AirBot" + ": Your name " + userName + "? I'm taking notes now...\n");

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is pretty much impossible (if you don't want to rewrite the whole `TextArea` skin). I recommend using a `ListView<String>` (or one containing a custom data type to seperate user and message) for this purpose and using a `cellFactory` that sets up this kind of bubble in the `updateItem` method of the returned `ListCell`s...

Comment: I think you can just use the lib https://github.com/zeppelsoftware/bluebub ;-)

Comment: ok thanks . let me check it